# Как добавить метод к иерархии классов

Tags: ооп, архитектура

Вопрос по архитектуре, но достаточно часто с этим сталкиваюсь, и редко вижу хорошее решение.

Предположим у нас есть некий интерфейс:

```
CoffeeMachine {
  doCoffee(); 
}
```

И у нас есть целая куча реализаций, LateCoffeeMachine, CapuchinoCoffeeMachine и т.д. И все идет хорошо, вот только нам вдруг нужно выводить куда нибудь параметры машины.

```
view(CoffeeMachine machine);
```

Но для каждого свои параметры, одна оперирует только количеством кофе, другая может еще и сахар, а третья еще и молоко.

Тут как бы кажется самым простым и логичным вариантом поменять интерфейс CoffeeMachine:

```
CoffeeMachine {
  doCoffee(); 
  view();
}
```

Вот только этот подход нарушает принцип Single Responsibility, ведь машина теперь отвечает не только за приготовление кофе, но еще и за отображения себя, так можно методы до бесконечности добавлять.

Второй вариант, который лично мне приходит в глову - это паттерн посетитель. Который на мой взгляд достаточно громоздкий.

Третий вариант, который мне приходит в голову, это через фабрику, создавать объекты парами. Однако такой метод приводит к появлению Generic (хотя можно и без них, но типобезопасность) и опять же некоторые проблемы.

```
Viewer<T> {
  view(T);
}
Factory {
  createMachine()
  createViewer();
}
```

В общем я и сам могу предложить ещё несколько решений, но мне было бы интересно посмотреть на чужой взгляд и чужие мысли на этот счет. Может я дико туплю и есть изящное решение или switch'a не избежать? )

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из моего опыта ООП я бы принял одно из двух решений:

1. Если поведение view специфично только для CoffeeMachine, то не вижу ничего плохого включить дополнительный метод в интерфейс. Это как раз будет очень правильно указывать на то, что у каждой CoffeeMachine есть представление, кроме того, что она может еще и кофе готовить.
2. Если поведение view не специфично для CoffeeMachine, а может быть присуще и другим элементам системы, то я бы выделил дополнительный интерфейс IViewable с методом view. Ну и, соответственно, указал, что соответствующие классы для приготовления кофе имплементируют не только интерфейс CoffeeMachine, но и интерфейс IViewable. Что позволит передавать ссылки на объекты данных классов в классы обработчики для отображения представлений. Для других элементов, которые также должны быть обработаны для представления также нужно указать, что они имплементируют интерфейс IViewable, но уже без CoffeeMachine, что не противоречит логике работы с объектами.

Второй вариант решения подходит только в том случае, если позволена множественная имплементация (думаю, что это сейчас почти во всех системах есть).
А всякие там фабрики - лишнее усложнение. имхо.

Comment: 2й вариант на мой взгляд лучше - выполняет правило о маленьких интерфейсах из SOLID. Но вот просто проблемы нет, когда возникает мысль "а не добавить ли мне 2 или 3й метод (или интерфейс) в класс?", Но когда таких вот методов накапливается под 10-20 и они уже очень косвенно относятся друг к другу, начинаешь потихоньку задумываться об архитектуре ) НАсчет фабрик кстати очень спроно. С одной стороны мы получаем более чистую архитектуру и большую гибкость, с другой стороны вы правы - система усложняется кучей порой ненужных абстракций.

Comment: По опыту проектирования - у меня интерфейсы редко содержат больше двух методов. Не знаю почему. Может быть это обусловлено теми задачами, которые мне необходимо решать. В основном это интеграция нескольких процессов с передачей друг-другу различных данных. Поэтому городить один большой интерфейс неправильно, так как многие методы просто повиснут в заглушки при реализации. А вот много маленьких интерфейсов позволяют гибко управлять протоколами обменов. Большие интерфейсы нужны для библиотек имхо. Когда нужно декларировать набор несвязанных методов.